# Add margin at the top of each page with a fixed text (print view)

Tags: css

When printing (Control + P), and have multiple pages, I am setting a fixed text at the top of each page. However, I need to add margin at the bottom of that text in a way it's not causing issue with the page content.

```
@media print {
    table.tblStandard {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
    }
    table {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add your complete HTML markup with the rest of its CSS, please? Currently, I cannot reproduce fully your example. Maybe it is worth to create a stackblitz?

Comment: this may help: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-7hy9gy?file=index.js

Comment: Have you tried setting a margin-top for the printed pages? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page

Comment: @CBroe Yes but the fixed table is also margined with the content.

Comment: probably we can override that using `@page .tblStandard` ?

Comment: Changing the `top` coordinate for that element, to the negative amount of the margin used, should probably work?

Comment: Nope because I set margin to @page, and content can't go above that.

Comment: @csandreas1 did you found a solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
.printmargin {display:none;height:50px;}
@media print {
    .printmargin {display:block !important}
}
```